# Как обозначается мягкость/твердость согласных в сочетаниях НС/НЗ?

Tags: орфография, мягкий-знак

Мы имеем:

пансионат (тв.Н) - пенсия (мягк.Н), но: июньский (мягк.Н),

вонзить (тв. Н) - вензель (мягк. Н)

С этими словам "что-то не так" - по слуху не всё пишется, а почему?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
По-моему, ассимиляция по мягкости не устаревает, а только НАЧИНАЕТ устаревать, и это в первую очередь коснулось сочетания НС/ЗС. Пожалуйста, проверьте этот текст. С чем вы в нем не согласны?

При обозначении мягких согласных Ь не пишется  в сочетаниях  5-ти зубных согласных Д/Т,  З/С и  Н, так как первый звук в таких сочетаниях  имеет «несобственную» мягкость (условный термин).В качестве справочной информации можно назвать,  в каких именно сочетаниях происходит взаимное влияние согласных:А). Звуки З/С смягчаются как перед Н, так  и перед Д/Т;  Д/Т и Н также взаимно смягчаются. Б) Сочетание звуков Д/Т и З/С к этой орфограмме просто не относится, так как здесь происходит другие изменения, а именно: сочетание звуков Т и С произносится  как  звук Ц.  В) Сочетания НС/НЗ  имеют определенные особенности.

Далее приведены практические примеры:
З/С перед Н :резня, возня, жизнь, казнь, кузнец, песня, басня, краснеть, блеснёт повиснет; З/С перед Д/Т: гвозди, грозди, грузди раздеть, здесь, сделать, стена, кисть, месть, мести упасть,  крестик, постель, ластик костюм, мастер, пасть, везти, влезть; Н перед ДТ: мундир, командир, бантик, фантик, лентяй;  ДТ перед Н: родня, беготня, сотня, сотник

В сочетании зубных согласных НС Ь пишется в двух словах: июньский и день-деньской.  Эти слова считаются исключениями, но фактически в них звук Н перед ТВЕРДЫМ С имеет собственную мягкость, которая обозначается с помощью Ь по общему правилу.

Н перед  мягкими З/С может произноситься как мягко (пенсия, гортензия, вензель), так и твердо (пансионат, в линзе, вонзить), что  говорит о СИЛЬНОЙ ПОЗИЦИИ ЗВУКА (для сравнения: пронзать – пронзить, звук Н остается твердым при изменении мягкости звука.Тем не менее, на письме сочетание зубных звуков Н и З/С среди остальных никак не выделяется, Ь в этих сочетаниях не пишется:

Comment: >пенсия (мягк.Н)  
  
???

>вензель (мягк. Н)

???

>С этими словам "что-то не так" - по слуху не всё пишется, а почему?    
  
Наверное что-то со слухом.  

София, а вы не с Украины? Там подобная регрессивная ассимиляция по мягкости весьма распространена. Правда в отношении именно этих слов я не такого слушал.

Comment: В старомосковском произнношении, насколько знаю, тоже так. Помню как возмущался, когда на курсе "Современного русского языка" заставляли транскрибировать че[т'в'эр']г.

Comment: Ой ли???
Это "четверг"? 
И так по-старомосковски? Неужели Т и Р мягкие?!

Но в любом случае в теме-то речь о регрессивной ассимиляции Н перед мягкими С/З. Она-то уж точно не старомосковская. Там скорее наоборот, Н отвердевает. Я еще застал времена, когда подобное было принято у стариков во МХАТе. Мне это было особенно непривычно после харьковского двора.  
  
Посмотрел. Да, действительно "пен**ь**сия" - это старомосковская норма. Значит, и "вен**ь**зель". Но это сейчас в Москве не услышишь от москвичей. Вот от украинцев нечто подобное (в других словах) = запросто.

Answer (score 1):

Регрессивная ассимеляция по мягкости устаревает, поэтому в большинстве слов современного языка её уже нет. Почему сохранилось в "пенсии" и  "вензеле" не знаю, возможно наложил отпечаток и звук [э] перед мягким согласным.

Что касается графики, то в "июньский" и пр. мягкий знак есть и в изначальном слове, а ассимеляцию на письме мы не обозначаем (см. *поезд*, а не *пое**ст**)*.

Comment: Не так немножко. Не обозначается ассимиляция, когда она вытекает из общих правил. Не помню сейчас точного списка оных. 

Пенсия и вензель - в современной орфоэпии Н четко твердый . 
Как и Р в январский - именно в силу регрессивной ассимиляции под действием твердого С. А в июньский - Н мягкий. Н менее поддается подобной ассимиляции.

Comment: @behenotus, согласно "Новому орфоэпическому словарю [Ссылка](http://books.google.ru/books?id=BeIJAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA359&lpg=PA359&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=AbwO-4PL82&sig=ioqErYt-rVX4Bkhb20mXSqNPB3M&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=6rGqUsi5MsKn4gTew4DADg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg), как раз твёрдое произношение неправильно. Сам я, живя далеко от Украины никогда не слышал "пенсия" с твёрдым [н].

Comment: Я произношу с мягким Н. И очень жаль, что уходит это старомосковское произношение. У нас фонетику преподавала ученица самого Аванесова, я просто наслаждалась её напевной речью. Мягкость, правильные редуцированные создавали такую неповторимость, особенность для нас, дальневосточников (хотя именно у нас очень много переселенцев с Украины).

Comment: А  почему  не  прогрессивная  ассимиляция  имеет  место  быть  в  словах  пенсия  и  вензель.  Попробуйте   произнести   пЭнсия,  вЭнзель.  И  "н"  и  "з"  сразу  тврдеют.